# Are these percentages calculated right for comparing two groups' attitudes?

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, survey, percentage

I'm interpreting results of a research I'm working on and I think the percentages are calculated falsely.
I'd like to make sure that everything is correct.
the research is about comparing two groups' attitudes and the calculated sample size is : 366 participants.
Medical students: 169
Non-medical students:197

what do you think of these results:
are the percentages calculated right?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "collected the data falsely", but if you mean that the data is fraudulent or that there were other problems at the data-collection phase of this project, I can't see any such problems from this table.

That said, I agree with your intuition that these are the wrong percentages. If you want to compare the two groups' attitudes, you should compute the proportion of people who answered "yes" within each group, not the proportion of each group who gave each answer, which is what's shown here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.                                                               I meant calculated the data falsely. My bad.                                          Could you please explain how should I calculate the percentages in the correct way in the example shown above?

Comment: You want 166 ÷ (166 + 3) and 189 ÷ (189 + 7).